# Is that possible I lexical binding special var in other package?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a very weird requirement that lexically binding a special variable of another package.

In file `A.lisp`

```lisp
(defpackage A
  (:use #:CL)
  (:export #:a-test))
(in-package A)
(declaim (special *a-sp-v*))
(defun a-test (&key (v *a-sp-v*))
  (print v))
```

in file `B.lisp`

```lisp
(defpackage B
  (:use #:CL #:A))
(in-package B)

(defun b-test ()
  (let ((*a-sp-v* 1))  ; cannot let a-test know
    (a-test)))
```

I keep receiving the error `The variable A::*A-SP-V* is unbound.` in my REPL.

Are there some methods I can bind `*a-sp-v*` in the package `B`? Let `a-test` function running with special `*a-sp-v*` no matter what package it is in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine (I would use [`defvar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm) instead of `declaim` `special` though).
You *can* bind any symbol, it does *not* matter which package it resides in.

You just need to make sure you bind the symbol you need to bind and not something else.
E.g., since you are *not* exporting `a::*a-sp-v*` from `a`, your `b-test` binds `b::*a-sp-v*` rather than `a::*a-sp-v*`.
If you replace `*a-sp-v*` with `a::*a-sp-v*` in `b-test`, it should work.
Alternatively, you can add `#:*a-sp-v*` to the `:export` section in `(defpackage A ...)`

Comment: Thank you very much. I bind `a::*a-sp-v*` in `b-test`, and it works fine. I `:export` `*a-sp-v*` in `A`, it doesn't work at first because I just `(defvar *a-sp-v*)`. I fixed it with `(defvar *a-sp-v* 1)` (give a value to `*a-sp-v*`), then I can bind `*a-sp-v*` directly in `b-test`. Thanks